# jquery make search auto suggest list open from down to up (opposite direction)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have created a search box with auto suggestion using jquery. The problem is that my list opens as usual from top to down. How can I make it open in the opposite direction, from down to up?

This the html code:

```
<input name="search" type="text" id="search_form_1" size="65" placeholder=" Search..."/>
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" />
```

This is my CSS:

```
#search_result{
padding:0px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(210, 210, 210, 210);
background:#333;
color:white;
position:absolute;
cursor:pointer;
}

#search_form_1{               
float: left;
padding-top:6px;
padding-left: 0px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px; color:#333;
}
```

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var left = $('#search_form_1').position().left;
var top = $('#search_form_1').position().top;
var width = $('#search_form_1').width();

$('#search_result').css('left', left+4).css('top', top-50).css('width',width);

$('#search_form_1').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    if(value != ''){

        $.post('search_form.php', {value: value}, function(data){
            $('#search_result').html(data);
        }); 

    }

});

});
```

and finally this is my php code, that calls and displays names in list:

```
<?php

  $value = $_POST['value'];

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `surname` FROM `users` WHERE `surname` LIKE '$value%' ");

  while($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $surname = $run['surname'];
    echo "$surname";
  }
?>
```

Comment: any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery position utility like,

```
$(function() {
function position() {
  $( ".positionable" ).position({
    of: $( "#parent" ),
    my: $( "#my_horizontal" ).val() + " " + $( "#my_vertical" ).val(),
    at: $( "#at_horizontal" ).val() + " " + $( "#at_vertical" ).val(),
    collision: $( "#collision_horizontal" ).val() + " " + $( "#collision_vertical" ).val()
  });
}
```

Here my is the child element and at is the parent element

Comment: I copy and paste it under my jquery code, but not working. Any idea how and where to place it?

Comment: read this: http://jqueryui.com/position/